# How to set style for n-th td in a table using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table with 10 columns . How I can write css classes that set style for all `TD`s in 2 or 7 position ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
tr td:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(7) {
    /* style here */
}
```

It's [not supported in IE8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t38). But here's a very nice polyfill: [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/).

Alternatives:

1. Use jQuery
2. Add a custom class to each 2nd and 7th td